# Why does a CAN 2.0A network identifier have a limit of 2032 values?

Tags: can-bus

In CAN 2.0, a network identifier with 11 bits has a limitation of 2032 identifier values (2<sup>11</sup> − 2<sup>4</sup>). Why does it have this limit instead of 2048 (2<sup>11</sup>)?

Comment: some (16) identifiers are reserved?

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/the-can-protocol/can-messages-33/:

> Due to compatibility with a certain old CAN controller, identifiers must not have the 7 most significant bits set to all ones, so only the identifiers `0..2031` are left.

Digging further (http://www.microchip.com/forums/m772846.aspx), it is blamed on a limitation/restriction of a 1980s Intel CAN controller (82526):

> In order to work with these chips the "restriction" was included in the Bosch and other early specs, but isn't in the current ISO spec. Unless you're using ancient hardware you can ignore this. If you are using ancient hardware, then the software running on that system shouldn't be using those IDs anyway.

In summary, unless you are running some ancient hardware, you should be able to use these "forbidden" identifiers.